# Returning a model in an array removes data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to return an array with a couple values in it - one is a `Customer` object. However, when I return it in the `array`, the data is lost - but if I return the *variable* alone, it looks just fine.

```
public function getUser($id) {

    $user = User::find($id);
    $likes = $user->itemLikes;
    $customer = $user->customer->get()->first();
    //return $customer;
    return Response::make(array('likes' => $likes, 'customer' => $customer), 200);
}
```

Without array: 
[image]

With array:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
return Response::make(array('likes' => $likes, 'customer' => $customer->toArray()), 200);
```

Comment: An explanation of what the difference is and why you need the changes would be helpful to anyone reading this in the future.